# Square Connect API merchant with bad credit or free account

Tags: square-connect

I'm building a new app for the Square marketplace and I would like to know after oAuth whether a merchant is a "free" user or has bad credit on Square. This would help me redirect merchant to a free subscription on our website.
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a "free user"?

Comment: A free user is somebody who doesn't have their payment method/bank account setup on Square. That's our understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that this is a very old question, but I just noticed the follow-up comment on it and hoped this answer might be useful to someone. The ability to process credit cards is a property of each merchant location. You can check the `capabilities` array on a [location](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#type-location) returned by the [ListLocations endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-listlocations) in the V2 API (this information is also available in the V1 API, but it's probably better and faster to use V2 in this case).

However, all Square merchant accounts are free per se, although credit card processing and some extra features might cost more money, so this answer may not be what you're looking for.